# Get height of two elements, set another element to that height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two elements. Both are dynamic. In Javascript or jQuery, I would like to grab the height of both of those elements and set the height of an element of the combined height of those two elements.

I know I can set one element of a another with:

```
$("#canvas-wrapper").height($("main.hero").height());
```

I tried to include a second element in area where the height gets grabbed such as:

```
$("div#canvas-wrapper").height($("header", "main.hero").height());
```

but that isn't working for me. Would I have to put two of those elements in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Using both selectors does not give you the combined height, you have to make separate calls for each:

```
$("div#canvas-wrapper").height($("header").height() + $("main.hero").height());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is syntactically wrong. You have to find each heights individually and add it together to get the heights.

To get the total height -

`var totHeight = $("header").height() + $("main.hero").height();`

To set it

`$("div#canvas-wrapper").height(totHeight);`

Or both in one sentence  like this

`$("div#canvas-wrapper").height($("header").height() + $("main.hero").height());`